# ffmpeg: What does s32 mean when dealing with a 24 bit wav file

Tags: audio

I have a 24 bit 48 KHz wav file, but when I feed it through ffmpeg, the stream looks like this:

```
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s
```

So, it clearly says `pcm_24le`, which, as I understand it, means pcm signed 24 bit little endian, but then it also says `s32`, with `24 bit` right after that. What does this mean? Is the file somehow both 24 bit and 32 bit, or does s32 mean something completely else in this case.

I've also experienced something a little similar when dealing with dts-streams. If I have an mkv file with a normal dts audio stream, it is recognised as dts 5.1, but when I've removed some streams from the file with ffmpeg, by using the -c copy command, it has suddenly become dts s32 5.1 in the new mkv file.

So, can s32 mean something else than signed 32 bit?

Comment: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/samplefmt.h It refers to the fact that when 24-bit audio is processed, they will be "unpacked" to 32-bit first, as 24-bit is inefficient (not power of 2; or something like that).

Comment: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n5.1.2/libavcodec/pcm.c#L622

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a reporting bug.

A similar bug-report was
[24bit FLAC shown as 32 bits per sample #23](https://github.com/simon-r/dr14_t.meter/issues/23),
which was supposed to have been fixed in 2018.
A comment said "The information printed by ffmpeg is always 32bit".

A similar bug-report but recent from 2022
[Include bits per sample in log #9](https://github.com/magicgoose/simple_dr_meter/issues/9),
which also says:

> It looks like it might be from a discrepancy with different fields within ffprobe. There's sample_fmt which is an internal representation and will say 32p for a file that's actually 24-bit, but the correct one we'd want is actually bits_per_raw_sample

Comment: I still have it with ffmpeg 6. and mpv.

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy between pcm_s24le (24-bit audio data) and s32 (32-bit containers for samples) often occurs because many systems and file formats don't natively support 24-bit integer. In such cases, 24-bit audio data is typically stored within a 32-bit container.

In the document of [scipy.io.wavfile.read](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) it can be found that when 24-bit audio data is stored in a 32-bit integer PCM format, it retains its 24-bit precision.

| WAV format | Min | Max | NumPy dtype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32-bit integer PCM | -2147483648 | +2147483647 | int32 |
| 24-bit integer PCM | -2147483648 | +2147483392 | int32 |